# jQuery Widget Factory setting options TypeError

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, widget, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I want to create a custom slider plugin in Widget Factory, but it doesn't work.  Why can't I use either the .option() function, or the .setMyOptions() custom function I created. I get the `TypeError: <function> is not a function error`.
What am I doing wrong? I know this is some simple syntax tweak and has to do with scopes, but I don't know what exactly is wrong.

```
    $.widget("custom.niceSlider", {

    options: { 
        value:0
    },

    myOptions: { 
        handleWidth:'30px' 
    },

    _create: function(){
        this.element.addClass("niceSlider");
        this._bar = $("<div class='bar' id='bar'></div>")
            .appendTo(this.element);
        this._handle = $("<div class='handle' id='handle'></div>")
            .appendTo(this._bar)
            .css("width", this.myOptions.handleWidth ); 
    },

    _destroy: function(){

    },

    _setOption: function( key, value ){

    },

    setMyOptions: function(key, value){
        switch(key){
            case 'handleWidth':
                this.myOptions.handleWidth = value;
                break;
        }
    }


});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
    slider.setMyOptions('handleWidth','50px');
});
```

Comment: Unless it is an anonymous function, a function must be declared as `function` first.  You are using `setMyOptions: function(key,value)` as a semi-anonymous function declared in a strange way.

Comment: Please describe how you are calling this? I would think you are doing `$(selector).niceSlider("setMyOption", "handleWidth", 100);`

Comment: Also why not extend the slider: `$.widget("custom.niceSlider", $.ui.slider, {});`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have a fair amount of work ahead of you to build your own slider widget. I would advise looking at just extending `$.ui.slider` a bit.

To address your question, I would examine this code:

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.niceSlider", {
    options: {
      value: 0,
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      orientation: "horizontal"
    },
    myOptions: {
      handleWidth: '30px'
    },
    _create: function() {
      this.element.addClass("ui-niceSlider ui-niceSlider-horizontal ui-widget");
      var barCount = $(".bar").length;
      barCount++;

      this._bar = $("<div>", {
          class: 'ui-niceSlider-bar ui-corner-all ui-widget-content',
          id: 'ui-niceSlider-bar-' + barCount
        })
        .appendTo(this.element);
      this._handle = $("<div>", {
          class: 'ui-niceSlider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default',
          id: 'ui-niceSlider-handle-' + barCount,
          style: "left: 0;"
        })
        .appendTo(this._bar)
        .css("width", this.myOptions.handleWidth);
    },
    setMyOptions: function(key, value) {
      console.log("setMyOptions", key, value);
      switch (key) {
        case 'handleWidth':
          this.myOptions.handleWidth = value;
          this.element.find(".ui-niceSlider-handle").css("width", this.myOptions.handleWidth);
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
  slider.niceSlider("setMyOptions", 'handleWidth', '50px');
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q6e7t3pn/2/

First, I noticed you had assigned IDs that would not be unique. This is fine for 1 slider, but not for more than 1. Other than that, there was nothing major wrong with the code. It was more about how you called it. There are three ways to do that:

```
var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
slider.niceSlider("setMyOptions", 'handleWidth', '50px');
```

Or:

```
var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
var niceSlider = $("#slider").data("niceSlider");
niceSlider.setMyOptions('handleWidth', '50px');
```

Or:

```
var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
$("#slider").niceSlider("instance").setMyOptions('handleWidth', '50px');
```

> **Plugin Invocation**
>
> To invoke a method using the widget's plugin, pass the name of the method as a string. ... If the method requires arguments, pass them as additional parameters to the plugin.
>
> **Instance Invocation**
>
> Under the hoods, every instance of every widget is stored on the element using `jQuery.data()`. To retrieve the instance object, call `jQuery.data()` using the widget's full name as the key. This is shown below.
>
> ...
>
> In jQuery UI 1.11, the new `instance()` method will make this process even easier.

From: [Widget Method Invocation](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/)

---

**Update**

You may want to consider a simplier solution:

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.niceSlider", $.ui.slider, {
    setMyOptions: function(key, value) {
      console.log("setMyOptions", key, value);
      switch (key) {
        case 'handleWidth':
          this.options.handleWidth = value;
          this.element.find(".ui-slider-handle").css("width", this.options.handleWidth);
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  var slider = $("#slider").niceSlider();
  slider.niceSlider("setMyOptions", 'handleWidth', '50px');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q6e7t3pn/4/